# How to check if a GridView contains a certain Button asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

hi i would like to know how can i check if any of the `reviewBtn` is visible in the gridview and if **ANY** `reviewBtn` is present, `btn_reviewAll` will be visible.

currently the code below only shows the `btn_reviewAll` when **ALL** reviewBtn is visible. pls advise thanks!

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewReview.Rows)
{
    Control reviewBtn = row.FindControl("ButtonReview") as Button;

    if (reviewBtn.Visible == true)
    {
       btn_reviewAll.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
       btn_reviewAll.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint at `reviewBtn.Visible` and view in **Quickwatch** what value you are getting for this control.

Comment: @Suprabhat the value is a `Text = "Review"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your code like this

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewReview.Rows)
{
    Control reviewBtn = row.FindControl("ButtonReview") as Button;

    if (reviewBtn.Visible == true)
    {
         btn_reviewAll.Visible = true;
         break;
    }
    else
    {
       btn_reviewAll.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

what it does is when one reviewBtn is visible it will set btn_reviewAll to visible and break out the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

@Shreesha's answer is absolutely correct, you can also do with less code using LINQ like this:-

```
if (GridViewReview.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>()
                  .Any(b => ((Button)b.FindControl("ButtonReview")).Visible))
      btn_reviewAll.Visible = true;
else
      btn_reviewAll.Visible = false;
```